# Proper way to chain multiple related db ( repository calls )

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

Using Spring WebFlux and ReactiveCrudRepository

Assume we have

```
UserRepository, UserDetailsRepository, UserTransactionRepository
```

I want to find the user, find their details and their transaction and return a single DTO object.
Separate calls would look lik

```
userRepo.findById
userDetailsRepo.findByUserId
userTransactionRepo.findByUserId
```

How id properly chain them?

```
userRepo.findById()
.map( u -> userDetails.findByUserId( u ))
.map( ud -> userTrans.findByUserId( u))
.map( data -> process....);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ReactiveCrudRepository, the `findById` method returns Mono from the emitted entity. You must use `flatMap()`.

```
return userRepo.findById(id)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new UserNotFoundException("User not found")))
                 .zipWhen(u -> userDetails.findById(u))
                  .zipWhen(ud -> userTrans.findById(ud))
                   .map(tuple -> mapper(tuple.getT1().getT1(), tuple.getT1().getT2(), tuple.getT2()));
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html

Comment: The catch here , i need to use values from all the three repos/tables and build one single combined object. The solution you gave just passes id to next step and returns the final transaction only

Comment: @madhairsilence, I updated the solution using `zipWhen()` method which combines all results into a tuple.